# Is it right to use compose of here

Tags: meaning, word-usage

For example,there are two kinds of human in the world, one is man, another is woman. Could I say that human is composed of men and women? Is it right to use *compose of* here? Or should I use *include*? Like this, Human include men and women. Thank you very much for any helps.

Comment: ***the** other*, not *another*.

Comment: I think _another_ is also right here. _another_ is a pronoun. For example, ‘It's a bill.’ ‘Oh no, not another!’ . One meaning of _another_ is _different; a different person or thing_. If I was wrong, please explain why ^_^ @FumbleFingers Thank you very much!

Comment: If there are only two of something, you have "one" and "the other". It doesn't make sense to say "another" if after "one" and "another" there's nothing else left to count.

Comment: What @Mixolydian said. There are some contexts where ***another*** can be used to refer to a second instance of something even if it's contextually certain there are only two altogether *(I'd rather be a kidney donor than a heart donor - at least you've got another in reserve!)*. But the sequence ***one is X, another is Y*** can only be used where there are known (or at least *believed*) to be more than two instances of whatever is being referenced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Compose**d** of" is a good expression to use here. But please note the "d" at the end of "composed".

Also the word "human" can be an adjective ("We are all human."), or it can be a noun meaning an individual person. The word you need in your sentence is "humanity", which means "all human beings everywhere".

So your sentence should be:

> "Humanity is composed of men and women."

Another way to say it is:

> "Humanity include**s** men and women."

because "humanity" is singular. Either sentence is correct.

Answer (score 1):

You need to speak more generically when talking of humans. The two most common phrases/words are "the human race" and "humanity". Human is a countable noun, and even using "humans" would potentially imply each human is both male and female.

> Humanity is composed of men and women.
>
> The human race includes men and women.

Either of these would be fine.